# Why passed input on HTML email validation?

Tags: html, angular, validation, email-validation

The following HTML code, accepts all input without validation.

Validation works only for not empty.

```html
<div class="input-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !PEmail.valid && submitted }">
    <input class="form-control"
           id="PEmail"
           name="PEmail"
           type="email"
           #PEmail="ngModel"
           [(ngModel)]="quote.FromAddress.Email"
           required
           email
           />
</div>
```

The code accept input like:
**'a', 'a@' 'a@a' 'a@a.com'**

How can I fix it to accept input like 'a@a' 'a@a.com'?

Comment: What do you want exactly ?

Comment: @MickaelB. i want to update this code to accept just valid emails like 'a@a' 'a@a.com' etc

Comment: a@a is a valid email for you ?

Comment: You said "The code accept input like: 'a', 'a@' 'a@a' 'a@a.com'"... And want to accept 'a@a' 'a@a.com' !?!?!?

Comment: yes, but myabe i made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Form validation is much easier with reactive forms and Angular has a built in email validator you can use for this.

Here's a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-forms-email-validation) showing how to implement it.